# Anexar Item do dropdowlist e uma li asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu tenho uma View com dropDowlist que contem dados que vem do banco e logo em baixo coloquei um buttom que quando eu clicar vai anexar o item selecionado do dropdownlist em uma  lista, eu fiz um código aqui mas não está anexando, se eu colocar valores predefinidos funciona, mas os valores da dropDowlist não.

javascript

```
        $("#addPeca").click(function () {  
        var resultData = $("#ListaPecas option:selected").text();  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myselect = $('<ul>');
            $.each(resultData, function (index, key) {
                myselect.append($('<li></li>').val(key).html(key));
            });
            $('#listPeca').append(myselect.html());
        });

    });
```

Na minha view

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListaPecas, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PecasId,Model.Pecas,"Pecas",  new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListaPecas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <button class="btn  btn-info" type="button" id="addPeca">Adicionar</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Lista onde sera anexado o valor selecionado

```
  <ul id="listPeca"></ul>
```

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Não faz sentido você ter um `$(document).ready()` dentro do evento de click do botão `#addPeca`. Modifiquei e transferi a lógica de manipulação da sua `<ul id="ListPeca">` para um método que é executado tando no click do botão, quanto no carregamento da página, assim ela já viria montada via `JQuery` com as options marcadas como `selected` na rederização da `View` pelo `@Html.DropDownListFor()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addPeca").click(function() {
    atualizaLista();
  });
  
  //primeira carga com as opções que já vieram selecionadas
  atualizaLista();
});

var atualizaLista = function() {
  //limpando o conteúdo da lista
  $("#ListPeca").html('');

  var resultData = $("#ListaPecas option:selected");
  var myselect = $('<ul>');
  $.each(resultData, function(index, key) {
    var peca = $(key);
    myselect.append($('<li>' + $(key).text() + '</li>'));
  });
  $(myselect.html()).appendTo("#ListPeca");
};
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ListaPecas" class="control-label col-md-2">
  Lista de Peças:
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select id="ListaPecas" class="form-control" placeholder="Lista de peças" multiple>
          <option value="peca1" selected>Peça 1</option>
          <option value="peca2">Peça 2</option>
          <option value="peca3" selected>Peça 3</option>
          <option value="peca4">Peça 4</option>
        </select>
    <button class="btn  btn-info" type="button" id="addPeca">Adicionar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <ul id="ListPeca">

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

> **Obs.:** Só pelo seu código ficou meio difícil compreender o seu objetivo,
>   deixo uma prévia da resposta e depois que você explicar melhor o
>   comportamento esperado eu edito.

Comment: Leandro Angelo -  È quase isso, mas não funciona com meu dropdowlist, só esta funcionando com o tipo "select". Resumindo, o que quero é selcionar algo da minha droplist já povoada com os dados do banco, e quando selecioanr vai fazer um append do item selecionado em uma ul li abaixo e mostrar o valor, essa ul li vai estar escondida e só aparece quando eu fazer append nela, já fiz tudo isso, unica coisa é que mesmo eu selecionando não está fazendo o append.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, eu tava colocando id do dropdowlist errado por isso esta retornando undefined , agora está certo.

```
        <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListaPecas, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PecasId,Model.Pecas,"Pecas",  new { @class = "form-control" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListaPecas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <button class="btn  btn-info" type="button" id="addPeca">Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul id="ListPeca"></ul>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
            $("#addPeca").click(function () {
            //Váriavel para checar se já existe na lista
            var chkRptTag = false;

            $('#ListPeca li').each(function () {
                haveSomeLi = true;
                var current = $(this).text();
                if (current == $("#PecasId option:selected").text()) {
                    chkRptTag = true;
                }
            });

            if (!chkRptTag) {
                $("#ListPeca").append("<li>" + $("#PecasId option:selected").text() + "<input type='checkbox' name='chkTags' id='chkTags' class='chkTags' checked='checked' value='" + $("#PecasId option:selected").val() + "'></li>");
            } else {
                alert("Peca Já inserida!");
            }
        });


        $('#ListPeca').on('click', "li", function () {
            $(this).remove();
            //alert();
            return false;
        });
```